# Use user id in bigquery SQL query that is passed into the function via an argument

Tags: python, sql, django, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the last synced data from bigquery for the given user

The query consists of this:

```
mc_query = """
        SELECT _fivetran_synced, connector_name
        FROM `database....`
        WHERE connector_name = 'pm_' + user.id + '_facebook_pages'
    """
```

This is the function below:

```
def facebook_last_pulled(user):

    # i've tried this code on the line below and replaced user.id with current_user_id in order to make sure the id is in the form of a string as well as using the CAST method on user id in the query
    #current_user_id = str(user.id)
    
    mc_query = """
        SELECT _fivetran_synced, connector_name
        FROM `database....`
        WHERE connector_name = 'pm_' + user.id + '_facebook_pages'
    """
    print(user.id)
    last_pulled_data = google_big_query(mc_query)
```

Where I print user.id I get the user id I'm looking for but when I put it into the query I get GenericGBQException, Reason: 400 Unrecognized name: user at [4:45]. So from the seems of it user isn't getting picked up in the variable mc_query, anyone know the reason I'm not getting user in there or a way to solve this?

I've tried setting a variable for user.id and using the variable instead of user.id as well as the CAST method in order to change it to a string inside the query.

I'm trying to get the fivetran_synced info from that user's row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an f-string, like this (note the leading f before the query):

```py
def facebook_last_pulled(user):

    mc_query = f"""
        SELECT _fivetran_synced, connector_name
        FROM `database....`
        WHERE connector_name = 'pm_' + {user.id} + '_facebook_pages'
    """
    last_pulled_data = google_big_query(mc_query)
```

Notice however that this may be prone to SQL injection. Instead, it may be recommended to use this implementation

```py
def facebook_last_pulled(user):
    
    mc_query = """
        SELECT _fivetran_synced, connector_name
        FROM `database....`
        WHERE connector_name = 'pm_' + ? + '_facebook_pages'
    """
    last_pulled_data = google_big_query(mc_query, user.id)
```

However this may not work (I have never used the function google_big_query and I don't know where it comes from). But a similar implementation works with MySQL or SQLite so it might work. It would in such a case fill in all question marks with the arguments passed to the executing query function.
Although this may not work, it may nudge you in the correct direction.

(The first implementation that is SQL unsafe should work though, so if potentially malicious end users don't have access to calling this function, it may be acceptable.)